# What is wrong with my manifest and Braintree paypal exeption?

Tags: paypal, nativescript, android-manifest, native, nativescript-angular

I'm working on payment in Native script angular and after I added everything like in instructions the error occured:

```
com.braintreepayments.api.exceptions.BraintreeException: BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity missing, incorrectly configured in AndroidManifest.xml or another app defines the same browser switch url as this app. See https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/client-sdk/android/v2#browser-switch for the correct configuration
```

Yeah i searched for solution but remaking my manifest didn't work for me. I have no idea what to do because every question ends with modyfying manifest... even if I change

```
<data android:scheme="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication${applicationId}.braintree"/>
```

for

```
<data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree"/>
```

My manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="org.nativescript.MobileApplication"
android:versionCode="10000"
android:versionName="1.0">

<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/nativescript_google_maps_api_key" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
```

android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

```
        <meta-data
         android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH"
          android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.braintreepayments.api.BraintreeBrowserSwitchActivity" 
android:launchMode="singleTask">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication${applicationId}.braintree"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
```

What can I do then? If you have some ideas help me please, best regards.

Comment: Or maybe do you have any simple tutorial how to make payment in another way not neccessary in PayPal? I need somethink fast to make in sandbox

Comment: Can you confirm which plugin you are using at present?

Comment: Are you testing in device / emulator? Do you have other apps installed on the device / emulator that includes this plugin?

Comment: @Manoj I'm testing on android emulator. Plugin is installed via tns add plugin pluginname. On symulator I don't have other apps. In addition I'm using google maps sdk plugin for google map which works perfectly.

Comment: @Manoj the actual plugin is Paypal checkout from https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-paypal-checkout

Comment: The plugin doesn't do much, hardly calls the native APIs from the SDK. As per the SDK developers, [there must be another app / build listening to the url scheme on the device / emulator](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_android/issues/174#issuecomment-350775357).

Answer (score 0):

with Braintree version 6 they deprecated that activity and removed it. Do a search for Braintree browser switching. you will need to add intent-filters to your manifest inside existing activities which receive a deep linking intent